# Enable ssl and force the algorithm to TLSv1,TLSv1.2,SSLv3 -Karate Framework

Tags: ssl, karate

I am trying to configure SSL in karate-config.js like below.

`karate.configure('ssl','TLSv1')`

or

`* configure ssl = 'TLSv1.2'`

The above both codes are working fine.

In my case I need to add 3 values in SSL (TLSv1,TLSv1.2,SSLv3 )

How can I configure all three value of ssl in karate.

I have referred https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#configure this. But unable to find a solution.

Comment: Enabling TLSv1 or SSLv3 may be replaced by just removing TLS completely in term of security level, this is mostly the same. Better really clearly no security than the illusion of security.

Comment: @PeterThomas What is not defined? The software clearly has `ssl` configuration option as a boolean, so I am just saying it is better to disable it than trying to use with SSLv3, or TLSv1 that make no sense to use nowadays.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek my bad, when I commented - I mean to tag OP. my message for Dilin is as commenter above said, just disable ssl for karate. or please explain what your specific need is (as no karate user has requested this yet) and if you can contribute code to karate that is ideal